# Content Security Policy Header not stopping attack

Tags: xss, content-security-policy, header

I created a simple test web application to test the use of the content security policy header. I included a vulnerability in my test app, such that submitting a basic XSS payload with script tags would be reflected back in full and execute a javascript alert...simple stuff.  I included a basic CSP header:

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'
```

I assumed this would stop the XSS, due to "CSP solves this problem by banning inline script entirely" https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/csp/

But, the js alert is still popping. I was able to verify that the header is being returned in the server response as expected. I tested with several up-to-date browsers (chrome, firefox, ie11). I applied the header in iis as follows:

```
# IIS Web.config
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src 'self';" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Is my implementation incorrect, or are my expectations wrong here?

Comment: Could you add the source of the example page you were using to the question?

Comment: Unfortunately, this test app is a shared project, that I can't get too specific into the source. Any idea from a general perspective?

Comment: I tested:
IE: 11.1387.15063.0
Firefox: 62.0
Chrome: 69.0.3497.100

Comment: I just tried this on latest Chrome and it was correctly blocked. In dev tools you can see "Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive" I suspect the header isn't appearing on the right page for some reason. Check it with an intercepting proxy.

Comment: Thanks paj28, this pointed me in the right direction! Turns out it was working in chrome (albeit, blocking more than I wanted!), but needed dev tools to confirm. IE was not working, but, does ie11 even support this header? This link mentions no support on ie10 but is dark on ie11. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [from comment] ... IE was not working, but, does ie11 even support this header?

According to [can i use content security policy](https://caniuse.com/#feat=contentsecuritypolicy) there is only partial support in IE11: only the `sandbox` directive is supported and the header needs to be specified as `X-Content-Security-Policy`. Thus, no support in IE11 for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

As Steffen mentioned, CSP is not fully supported on IE 11. Your code was definitely not wrong from my perspective (particularly given it was fine in Chrome).

This tool for checking CSP compatibility may prove useful in the future: https://content-security-policy.com/browser-test/